# Xsd schema not returning wanted xml file

Tags: xml, csv, xsd, oracle-integration-cloud

In OIC I read a file based on a xsd schema. The output of the file is not How I expected or wanted it to be.

I have this xsd schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:nxsd="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/nxsd"
           xmlns:tns="http://supoc.oracle.com/RICEFData"
           targetNamespace="http://supoc.oracle.com/RICEFData"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           nxsd:stream="chars"
           nxsd:version="NXSD"
           nxsd:encoding="UTF8"
           nxsd:encodeLineTerminators="false"
>
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="RICEFData">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ENV" nxsd:startsWith='"ENV"|'>
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="C2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C5" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C6" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C7" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C8" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C9" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C10" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C11" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="HDR" nxsd:startsWith='"HDR"|'>
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="C2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C5" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C6" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C7" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C8" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C9" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C10" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C11" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C12" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C13" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C14" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C15" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C16" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C17" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C18" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C19" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C20" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C21" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C22" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C23" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C24" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C25" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C26" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C27" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C28" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C29" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C30" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C31" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C32" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C33" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C34" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C35" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C36" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C37" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C38" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C39" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C40" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C41" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C42" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C43" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C44" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C45" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C46" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="LIN" nxsd:startsWith='"LIN"|'>
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="C2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C5" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C6" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C7" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C8" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C9" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C10" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C11" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C12" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C13" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C14" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C15" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C16" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C17" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C18" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C19" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C20" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C21" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C22" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C23" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C24" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C25" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C26" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C27" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C28" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C29" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C30" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C31" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C32" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C33" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C34" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C35" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C36" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C37" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C38" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C39" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C40" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C41" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C42" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C43" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C44" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C45" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C46" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C47" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C48" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C49" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C50" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C51" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C52" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C53" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C54" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C55" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C56" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C57" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C58" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C59" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C60" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C61" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C62" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C63" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                                <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="LTX" nxsd:startsWith='"LTX"|'>
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="C2" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C3" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C4" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C5" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C6" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C7" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="|"/>
                                            <xs:element name="C8" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" nxsd:style="terminated" nxsd:terminatedBy="${eol}"/>
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

It reads a csv file that contains different records with each a different amount of fields

Now the problem is as followed.
Example file that is read:

"ENV"|........
"HDR"|........
"LIN"|........
"LTX"|........
"LTX"|........
"LIN"|........
"LTX"|........
"ENV"|........
"HDR"|........
"LIN"|........
"LTX"|........

See it as this. ENV contains ticket data HDR contains Ticket Details. Lin contains item data LTX contains item info.

So each ticket kan have multiple items.

How I want my output of the file:

```
<RicefData>
   <env>
      (All the data)
   </env>
   <HDR>
      (All the data)
   </HDR>
   <LIN>
      (All the data)
   </LIN>
   <LTX>
      (All the data)
   </LTX>
   <LTX>
      (All the data)
   </LTX>
   <LIN>
      (All the data)
   </LIN>
   <LTX>
      (All the data)
   </LTX>
</RicefData>
<RicefData>
   <env>
      (All the data)
   </env>
   <HDR>
      (All the data)
   </HDR>
   <LIN>
      (All the data)
   </LIN>
   <LTX>
      (All the data)
   </LTX>
</RicefData>
```

BUT this is how I get the output:

```
<RicefData>
   <env>
      (All the data)
   </env>
   <HDR>
      (All the data)
   </HDR>
   <LIN>
      (All the data)
   </LIN>
   <LTX>
      (All the data)
   </LTX>
   <LTX>
      (All the data)
   </LTX>
   <LIN>
      (All the data)
   </LIN>
   <LTX>
      (All the data)
   </LTX>
   <env>
      (All the data)
   </env>
   <HDR>
      (All the data)
   </HDR>
   <LIN>
      (All the data)
   </LIN>
   <LTX>
      (All the data)
   </LTX>
</RicefData>
```

What Do I need to change in my schema So I have multiple RicefData fields?

It will always be max 1 env and hdr in a ricefData block. and LIN and LTX can be unlimited.

Comment: You seem to be using some kind of software that uses an XSD schema in the course of converting CSV to XML. You need to tell us what that software is, and tag your question accordingly to bring it to the attention of people who know that software.

Comment: A well formed XML file has only one root element.  What you want has multiple RicefData elements at the root.  Add one Root element as the parent of the arrays of RicefData and your issue will be solved

Comment: Looks like they are using Oracle Integration Cloud, mentioned as OIC at the beginning of his post, I've added that tag